# Are there simple ways to write/read records to/from fifos in VHDL/FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

Assuming a fifo with record type in and out, is there a simple way to handle the mapping between the record type in the input and output of the fifo wrapper and std_logic_vector in the actual fifo?

Comment: Assuming I understand this correctly, you already have decided to use records for your input/output to your FIFO - why don't you use functions that take the record as input and return a std_logic_vector and vice versa.

Comment: Assumption is correct. Would you have an example, where these functions are simplified/less error prone to write than what is shown in the example answer?

Comment: I will add an example, not sure about its ability to be less error prone - I guess you can judge that better.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You are right - the verification becomes a matter if taste. Overall, my aim was to hide the dirty work under the hood as much as possible, so the use of the fifo doesn't need to know how that happens. I agree that with functions the same can be achieved. The problem becomes with multiple fifos and how to maintaint the fifo elements from name-clashing.

Comment: Which FIFO elements are you worried about? Perhaps a little example is warranted here? You could use different packages to avoid name clashes - I am assuming here, hard to comment without much detail.

Answer (score 1):

As presented, you can hide the conversation in a package. So you have 2 functions to and from FIFO interface to a record.

Rob Gaddi (vice-chair at the IEEE WG for VHDL) presented once a set of helper procedures for faster packing and unpacking std_logic_vectors to and from record types.
See his [proposed pack and unpack subprograms](http://www.eda-twiki.org/twiki/pub/P1076/RecordReflectionToSlv/standard_functions.vhd).

The working group itself had long discussions on how to solve such an issue. There are 3 possibilities:

- VHDL supports generic types on entity declarations. So a VHDL-2008 compliant synthesis tool could create a generic FIFO accepting any type *) as a FIFO element.
- [VHDL-2017](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/VHDL2017) adds a [reflection API](http://www.eda-twiki.org/cgi-bin/view.cgi/P1076/LCS2016_041) that can at least solve the conversation from record to `std_logic_vector`. I'm working on a idea how to implement the reverse path.
- A direct solution to iterate record elements was not found yet and is delayed to the next revision (VHDL-2020)

*) Any synthesizable scalar, array or record type.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that I've been able to come up with so far is as follows:

First a function package to tidy up constant range declaration:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package Fun_pck is
  function fLenAtTopOf(a : natural; b: std_logic_vector) return natural;
  function fTopOf(b : std_logic_vector) return natural;
end package Fun_pck;
package body Fun_pck is
  function fLenAtTopOf(a : natural; b: std_logic_vector) return natural is
  begin
    return a+b'left;
  end function fLenAtTopOf;
  function fTopOf(b: std_logic_vector) return natural is
  begin
    return b'left+1;
  end function fTopOf;
end package body Fun_pck;
```

Then two packages that contains helper definitions for the fifo:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.Fun_pck.all;

package ExampleFifo_pck_private is

-- This package is 'private', i.e. only meant to be seen by the package and
-- entity in this file. This is so that the elements will not have a name
-- clash. As they are top-level constants that would be a likely problem.
-- Fifo element constants.
  type width_array is array (integer range <>) of integer;
  constant cElementWidths : width_array(0 to 2) := (4, 8, 1);

  constant cFifoElement0 : std_logic_vector(cElementWidths(0)-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  constant cFifoElement1 : std_logic_vector(
    fLenAtTopOf(cElementWidths(1), cFifoElement0) downto
    fTopOf(cFifoElement0)) := (others => '0');
  constant cFifoElement2 : std_logic_vector(
    fLenAtTopOf(cElementWidths(2), cFifoElement1) downto
    fTopOf(cFifoElement1)) := (others => '0');

-- General Form:
--constant cFifoElementN : std_logic_vector(
--  fLenAtTopOf(cElementWidths(N), cFifoElement[N-1]) downto
--  fTopOf(cFifoElement[N-1])) := (others => '0');
end package ExampleFifo_pck_private;  

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.Fun_pck.all;
use work.ExampleFifo_pck_private.all;

-- Fifo item type
  type tExampleFifoData is record
    A : std_logic_vector(cFifoElement0'length-1 downto 0);
    B : std_logic_vector(cFifoElement1'length-1 downto 0);
    C : std_logic_vector(cFifoElement2'length-1 downto 0);
  end record tExampleFifoData;

-- Reset constant 
  constant cResetExampleFifoData : tExampleFifoData := (
    A => cFifoElement0,
    B => cFifoElement1,
    C => cFifoElement2
    );
-- Length Constant
  constant cExampleFifoWidth : integer := fTopOf(cFifoElement2);
  -- Data array type
  type tExampleFifoData_Array is array (natural range<>) of tExampleFifoData;
end package ExampleFifo_pck;
```

and finally entity/architecture pair that wraps the fifo module, in this case Xilinx xpm:

```
    library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use work.ExampleFifo_pck.all;  
    use work.ExampleFifo_pck_private.all;  

    library xpm;
    use xpm.vcomponents.all;

    entity ExampleFifo is
      port (
        iWrClk      : in  std_logic;
        iRst        : in  std_logic;
        iWrEn       : in  std_logic;
        iWrData     : in  tExampleFifoData;
        oWrFull     : out std_logic;
        oWrProgFull : out std_logic;
        iRdClk      : in  std_logic;
        iRdEn       : in  std_logic;
        oRdData     : out tExampleFifoData;
        oRdEmpty    : out std_logic
        );
    end entity ExampleFifo;

    architecture RTL of ExampleFifo is

    -- Internal vector signals 
      signal sWrData : std_logic_vector(cExampleFifoWidth-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
      signal sRdData : std_logic_vector(cExampleFifoWidth-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    begin

      sWrData(cFifoElement0'range) <= iWrData.A;
      sWrData(cFifoElement1'range) <= iWrData.B;
      sWrData(cFifoElement2'range) <= iWrData.C;

      oRdData.A <= sRdData(cFifoElement0'range);
      oRdData.B <= sRdData(cFifoElement1'range);
      oRdData.C <= sRdData(cFifoElement2'range);

      x_fifo : xpm_fifo_async
        generic map (
          -- check:
          FIFO_MEMORY_TYPE    => "distributed",  --string; "auto", "block", or "distributed";
          ECC_MODE            => "no_ecc",       --string; "no_ecc" or "en_ecc";
          -- check:
          RELATED_CLOCKS      => 0,              --positive integer; 0 or 1
          -- check:
          FIFO_WRITE_DEPTH    => 32,             --positive integer
          -- modify:
          WRITE_DATA_WIDTH    => cExampleFifoWidth,  --positive integer
          WR_DATA_COUNT_WIDTH => 1,              --positive integer
          -- check:
          PROG_FULL_THRESH    => 27,             --positive integer
          FULL_RESET_VALUE    => 0,              --positive integer; 0 or 1;
          read_mode           => "fwft",         --string; "std" or "fwft";
          FIFO_READ_LATENCY   => 0,              --positive integer;
          -- modify:
          READ_DATA_WIDTH     => cExampleFifoWidth,         --positive integer
          RD_DATA_COUNT_WIDTH => 1,              --positive integer
          PROG_EMPTY_THRESH   => 10,             --positive integer
          DOUT_RESET_VALUE    => "0",            --string
          CDC_SYNC_STAGES     => 2,              --positive integer
          WAKEUP_TIME         => 0               --positive integer; 0 or 2;
          )
        port map (
          sleep         => '0',
          rst           => iRst,
          wr_clk        => iWrClk,
          wr_en         => iWrEn,
          din           => sWrData,
          full          => oWrFull,
          overflow      => open,
          wr_rst_busy   => open,
          rd_clk        => iRdClk,
          rd_en         => iRdEn,
          dout          => sRdData,
          empty         => oRdEmpty,
          underflow     => open,
          rd_rst_busy   => open,
          prog_full     => oWrProgFull,
          wr_data_count => open,
          prog_empty    => open,
          rd_data_count => open,
          injectsbiterr => '0',
          injectdbiterr => '0',
          sbiterr       => open,
          dbiterr       => open
          );
    end architecture RTL;
```

This is a bit of trouble, but quite manageable to declare fifo. Each different fifo still needs own version the package and entity. Naturally they can be in a single file.

After this trouble, the actual use of the fifo is very simple:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.ExampleFifo_pck.all;

entity tb is
end entity tb;

architecture sim of tb is
  signal iWrClk      : std_logic := '1';
  signal iRst        : std_logic := '0';
  signal sWrEn       : std_logic := '0';
  signal sWrData     : tExampleFifoData;
  signal sWrFull     : std_logic;
  signal sWrProgFull : std_logic;
  signal iRdClk      : std_logic := '1';
  signal sRdEn       : std_logic := '0';
  signal sRdData     : tExampleFifoData;
  signal sRdEmpty    : std_logic;

  signal sTestIn  : tExampleFifoData     := cResetExampleFifoData;
  signal sTestOut : tExampleFifoData;
  constant tests  : tExampleFifoData_Array(0 to 1) :=
    (0 => (x"E", x"A7", "1"), 1 => (x"7", x"AC", "0"));
begin

  iWrClk <= not iWrClk after 5 ns;
  iRdClk <= not iRdClk after 7.2 ns;

  ExFifo : entity work.ExampleFifo
    port map (
      iWrClk      => iWrClk,
      iRst        => iRst,
      iWrEn       => sWrEn,
      iWrData     => sTestIn,
      oWrFull     => sWrFull,
      oWrProgFull => sWrProgFull,
      iRdClk      => iRdClk,
      iRdEn       => sRdEn,
      oRdData     => sTestOut,
      oRdEmpty    => sRdEmpty
      );

  wr : process is
  begin
    iRst <= '1';
    for i in 0 to 5 loop
      wait until rising_edge(iWrClk);      
    end loop;
    iRst <= '0';
    wait for 150 ns;
    for i in 0 to 1 loop
      wait for 15 ns;
      wait until rising_edge(iWrClk);
      sTestIn <= tests(i);
      sWrEn   <= '1';
      wait until rising_edge(iWrClk);
      sWrEn   <= '0';
      wait until rising_edge(iWrClk);
    end loop;
    wait;
  end process wr;

  rd : process is
  begin
    wait until rising_edge(iRdClk);
    sRdEn <= '0';
    if(sRdEmpty = '0' ans sRdEn <= '0') then
      sRdEn <= '1';
    end if;
  end process rd;

end architecture sim;
```

Answer (score 0):

Made to be brief...

```
-- items within fifo
constant c_items : integer := 8;
constant c_width : integer :=
(-- ADD NEW ITEMS HERE
    c_CWidth +
    c_BWidth +
    c_AWidth
);
type t_intVector is array (natural range <>) of integer;
constant c_start : t_intVector(c_items downto 0) :=
(-- INSERT/MODIFY FOR NEW ITEMS
    0+c_AWidth+c_BWidth+c_CWidth, -- end
    0+c_AWidth+c_BWidth,          -- C
    0+c_AWidth,                   -- B
    0                             -- A
);

-- MODIFY FOR ADDITIONAL ITEMS
procedure f_writeToFifo(
    signal o_f : out std_logic_vector;
           i_A :     unsigned;
           i_B :     unsigned;
           i_C :     unsigned) is
begin
    o_f <= i_C &
           i_B &
           i_A;
end procedure f_writeToFifo;

type t_data is record
    A : unsigned(c_AWidth-1 downto 0);
    B : unsigned(c_BWidth-1 downto 0);
    C : unsigned(c_CWidth-1 downto 0);
end record;

function f_readA(i_f : std_logic_vector) return unsigned is begin return unsigned(i_f(c_start(3)-1 downto c_start(2))); end function f_readA;
function f_readB(i_f : std_logic_vector) return unsigned is begin return unsigned(i_f(c_start(2)-1 downto c_start(1))); end function f_readB;
function f_readC(i_f : std_logic_vector) return unsigned is begin return unsigned(i_f(c_start(1)-1 downto c_start(0))); end function f_readC;
function f_read (i_f : std_logic_vector) return t_data is begin
    return ( C => f_readC(i_f),
             B => f_readB(i_f),
             A => f_readA(i_f) );
end function f_read;
```

Ignore the list/position/item creation. The procedure/record/functions are what I intended to highlight.